# Patching process for Grafana that is deployed using helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, helm3

I have deployed Grafana using helm chart and Terraform. We have exposed version as a input property so, we can run same script to update the version. I also have to support patching(any patch security etc.) similarly but I have no knowledge on how patches are released and how to apply them using Helm for Grafana..

Can someone please let me know ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking a look at this. I am able to get solution for this, patches are released as minor versions and it is no different from version upgrade.

Thanks.